# Using shader on opengl rectangle causes it to disappear

Tags: c++, opengl, shader

I'm currently trying to render a texture using OpenGL into a game engine I've been working on but have run into an issue I am unsure of how to solve. When utilizing my shader on a rectangle to render a texture, it simply does not show.

I can comment out one line of code and a black rectangle will show so I know the rectangle is rendering correctly at least. The problem is when I ask OpenGL to use my shader program.

Here with the `ourshader.Use` line commented out

```
// Clear the colorbuffer
glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

//ourShader.Use(); <----this is using the shader
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(ourShader.Program, "ourTexture"), 0);

// Draw container
glBindVertexArray(VAO);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
glBindVertexArray(0);
```

i get

[image]

without i just get

[image]

This is strange to me as in another test project i can render textures absolutely fine using the exact same code.

[image]

frag shader

```
#version 330 core
in vec3 ourColor;
in vec2 TexCoord;

out vec4 color;

// Texture samplers
uniform sampler2D ourTexture1;

void main()
{
    // Linearly interpolate between both textures (second texture is only slightly combined)
    color = texture(ourTexture1, TexCoord);
}
```

vert shader

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 color;
layout (location = 2) in vec2 texCoord;

out vec3 ourColor;
out vec2 TexCoord;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(position, 1.0f);
    ourColor = color;
    // We swap the y-axis by substracing our coordinates from 1. This is done because most images have the top y-axis inversed with OpenGL's top y-axis.
    // TexCoord = texCoord;
    TexCoord = vec2(texCoord.x, 1.0 - texCoord.y);
}
```

I've literally copied and pasted the code and can't seem to get the same result. One of the problems could be that I'm rendering this in a project that gets built as a .dll and then is referenced in another project in the same solution, yet I know OpenGL is working because I can still render the rectangle?

I've also tested this by drawing a simple untextured triangle and it works fine.

I could even use shaders on it and mess around with color and what not, so why would this texture shader not work? Especially confusing because I've tested this shader in another project and it works fine? So I am very stuck and have resorted to asking for help on here.

Comment: Where do you generate the texture name (`glGenTextures`)? Where do you specify the texture image [`glTexImage2D`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexImage2D.xhtml)? Is the OpenGL context valid (and current) when you specify the texture image? Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(ourShader.Program, "ourTexture"), 0);
```

You specify the location of a sampler with the name "ourTexture" but the sampler inside of your shader has the name "ourTexture1".

You can also specify the texture location inside of your shader explicitly with

```
layout (location = 0) uniform sampler2D ourTexture;
```

Then you only need to call

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
```

to bind your texture to the texture unit 0.

Comment: it worked! I noticed this before actually and changed the sampler name accordingly with no results but after testing it out again it seems to work? I must have missed something. Thanks for your answers! Admittedly, im an opengl noob and it seems to want to fight me every step of the way haha. This probably wont be the last you hear from me.Thanks again!